# User Notification Library

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently looking for a user notification library php/javascript that will allow a user to run a particular process (say add something to a database) and then allow them to continue the site and eventually give them a pop up message when the process is complete. This way a user can continue to use a particular site without having to wait for a query to be done. I have checked some libraries on this such as https://github.com/beberlei/litecqrs-php but I don't know if this actually does what I have described after reading it. Please let me know any ideas or if this library can do what I have described. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else may provide you with a link to a great library, but I'm gonna go ahead and say that you can do that with AJAX.  Javascript can send a request to the server for a php file to, for example, add something to a database.  Then, because it's asynchronous, the user can keep browsing and Javascript can keep doing stuff until AJAX is done, at which time the callback function will occur, and you can just place a nice little bit of Javascript code in there to notify the user that the process is done.

```
function addToDatabase(whatToAdd)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      //Notify user with result using xmlhttp.responseText
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","addToDatabase.php?toAdd="+whatToAdd,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You know, something like that.